# Extract Unique Orders

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

Please help me to write a SQL query to extract unique orders from below tables.  To do that I Have prepared a SQL query. It’s working fine but in some place its returning some duplicate rows as some orders have more than one products.

**For Example:**

Customer can buy “IPAD” in one order. However, if they purchase “Ipad” and “Android” as bundle they will receive 50% discount and they can save money. In this case, we will get two products under 1 order. However, customer will pay as one product(i.e $120). To allocate order properly, we have created an extra row for the extra product(if products  two). If bundle contain three products, it will create three rows in “product_orders” table respectively.

**Example “product_orders”** table for multiple products:

```
id orders_id product_id qty
 1   3      2         1
 2   2      1         1
 3   3      3         1
```

Please check above example table, one order_id copied twice for the bundle order.
If we able to extract one order information, we will get the whole bundle information. So, we don’t need the extra row.

**The Query I have applied:**

```
Select 
    orders.id, 
    orders.order_price, 
    orders.purchase_date,
    customers.email, 
    product_orders.qty, 
    products.name 
from 
    orders 
    INNER JOIN product_orders on orders.id=product_orders.orders_id 
    INNER JOIN products on product_orders.product_id=products._id 
    INNER JOIN customers on orders.customer_id =customers.id
```

`Result of the above query:`**

```
Id  order_price  purchase_date      email        qty         name 
3  20         12/6/2011     aa@gmail.com             1   Ipad

3  20         12/6/2011     aa@gmail.com             1   Android
1  40         10/5/2011     bb@gmail.com             2  Laser hair remover
```

**Required Result:**

remove duplicate order ID

```
Id  order_price  purchase_date      email        qty         name 
    3  20         12/6/2011     aa@gmail.com             1   Ipad


    1  40         10/5/2011     bb@gmail.com             2  Laser hair remover
```

**Table 1: orders**

```
id  customer_id order_price purchase_date
1   1                   0.20    12/6/2011
2   2                   0.20    12/6/2011
3   1                   0.20    12/6/2011
4   1                   0.20    12/6/2011
5   1                   0.20    12/7/2011
6   3                   199.00  12/7/2011
7   4                   199.00  12/7/2011
8   5                   199.00  12/7/2011
9   6                   199.00  12/7/2011
10  7                   199.00  12/7/2011
```

**Table 2 : customers**

```
id  email                   name
1   aa@dealboard.com.au aa
2   bb@dealboard.com.au bb
3   cc@live.com.au          cc
4   dd@acgglobal.com    dd
5   ee.heinrich@det.nsw.edu.au  ee
6   ff@optusnet.com.au  ff
7   ssy@hotmail.com         ss
```

**table 3: products**

```
id  name
1   A Home Portable Laser Hair Remover
2   Ipad
3   android
4   Asus
5   s
6   10 inch Android
7   A Fabric Steamer Cleaner
8   A Magnetic Fly Screen Door
9   pillopw
10  LCD
```

**table 4: product_orders**

```
id orders_id product_id qty
    1   1      1         1
    2   3      3         1
    3   3      4         1
    4   4      1         1
    5   4      2         1
    6   6      1         1
    7   7      1         1
    8   4      2         1
    9   4      3         1
    10  10     1         1
```

Please help me to extract only 1 order from “product_orders” table and the query will omit other extra rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add extra `subquery` which gets only one product per `order_id`

```
Select 
    orders.id, 
    orders.order_price, 
    orders.purchase_date,
    customers.email, 
    product_orders.qty, 
    products.name 
from 
    orders 
    INNER JOIN product_orders on orders.id=product_orders.orders_id 
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT orders_id, MIN(Product_ID) prodID
        FROM product_orders
        GROUP BY orders_id
    ) c ON product_orders.orders_ID = c.orders_id AND
            product_orders.Product_ID = c.prodID
    INNER JOIN products on product_orders.product_id=products.id 
    INNER JOIN customers on orders.customer_id =customers.id
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/608a5/2)

Comment: hi Jhone, please explain the following section "MIN(Product_ID) prodID
        FROM product_orders" pls. this will help me alot. thanks

Comment: that subquery gets the minimum value of the product ID per orders_id. run this `SELECT orders_id, MIN(Product_ID) prodID
        FROM product_orders
        GROUP BY orders_id` and you will set the result.

Answer (score 1):

You need three new tables:

```
Bundles (ID, Name)

BundleProducts (BundleID, ProductID)

OrderLines (ID, OrderID, ProductID, BundleID, Qty)
```

Lets say Bundles contains:

```
ID    Name
1     IPad & Android
```

And BundleProducts contains

```
BundleID    ProductID
1           2
1           3
```

Then when a customer adds a product to their order you insert the ProductID into the OrderLines table. If they add a Bundle, you insert into the BundleID. When the order is complete, you populate the Product_Orders table with each product from the OrderLines table where Product_ID is populated, and also each ProductID from the BundleProducts table if the ProductLines.BundleID is populated.

Alternatively you could make the bundles into products themselves. This would mean that you don't need the Bundles table, but you would still need the BundleProducts table. Also you would not need the BundleID column in OrderLines. So 'Ipad & Android Bundle' becomes a new product in the Products table.

When the order is complete you would do something like:

```
INSERT INTO 
    Product_Orders (Orders_id, Product_ID, Qty)
SELECT
    Orders.ID,
    COALESCE(BundleProducts.ProductID, OrderLines.ProductID),
    OrderLines.Qty
FROM
    Orders
    INNER JOIN OrderLines ON Orders.ID = OrderLines.Orders_ID
    LEFT JOIN BundleProducts ON OrderLines.ProductID = BundleLines.BundleID
```

Comment: thanks u very much. that will help me alot. i will discuss with my team about that. i like this site more and more. awesome.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select orders.id, orders.order_price, orders.purchase_date, customers.email, product_orders.qty, products.name 
from orders 
INNER JOIN product_orders on orders.id=product_orders.orders_id 
INNER JOIN products on product_orders.product_id=products._id 
INNER JOIN customers on orders.customer_id =customers.id
GROUP BY orders.id
```

Add in GROUP BY orders.id